# vb.NET determine what takes up the most space in my executables

Tags: vb.net

Is there a way to check what parts of my vb.NET application take up the most space? My application size increased by 4 MB within one week

Answer (score 0):

For an increase that drastic, I would guess that it involves resources that you've recently added.